# How to highlight text with background in a table with Prawn (prawn_to)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I want to set some background color to parts of the content in a cell in a Prawn table.

My code looks like this:

```
#file: /show.pdf.prawn
pdf.table([ ["Type XY", "150", "1245.45"],
            ["Type ZA", "100", "1243.50"],
            ["Type BC", "20", "645.00"] ])
```

Only the `XY`, `ZA`, and `BC` should have a corresponding background color. In HTML I would write: `<span style="background: yellow;">XY</span>` - but this inline format is not supported yet by Prawn.

The only hint the Prawn manual is giving me is: text -> formatted callbacks. But this doesn't work in a table.
Is there any possibility to do this? Is there any equivalent to the HTML `span`? Should I try a bounding box or an inner table?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rows = [["Type XY", "150", "1245.45"],
        ["Type ZA", "100", "1243.50"],
        ["Type BC", "20", "645.00"]]

pdf.table(rows) do
  column(0).background_color = "708DC6" #the color
end
```

I suggest you to create another stand-alone model for prawn like on this [tutorial](http://blog.idyllic-software.com/blog/bid/204082/Creating-PDF-using-Prawn-in-Ruby-on-Rails).

Hope can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example sets the background color for the whole first column - not just the "XY"-text snippet. I don't see any way to do this until Prawn adds any background-color tag to the inline stylings.

Comment: Did you tried for the with calculation method to coloring some cell on prawn manual? Yes It not what you're asking actually, but it can be looked as references answer perhaps? CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Just came across code that can help you with this. Format by [Cell](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn/Table/Cell) instead of Column on the Table.

```
pdf.table(rows) do
  cells.style do |c|
    if c.column == 0 and c.row == 0
      c.background_color = "708DC6"
    elsif c.column == 1 and c.row == 0
      c.background_color = "2944ce"
    elsif c.column == 2 and c.row == 0
      c.background_color = "008000"
    end
  end
end
```

Now only the header row has colors and you can choose per column.